# iOS localization in XCode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization

I'm having trouble getting started with localization. Specifically, the UI I see in XCode (7.1) is different than the UI on Apple's docs site.

According to Apple's docs, there should be a "Localizations" section under my project info, but I can't find it.

#### What apple's docs show

[image]

(From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html)

#### What I see

[image]

Similarly, I don't see a checkbox for "base internationalization", and if I try to add languages via Editor -> Add Localization all the menu items are unselectable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the left of your screenshot, there should be a little sidebar with two sections, "PROJECT" and "TARGETS". Select the item under "PROJECT", and then, select the 'General' tab. You should see it there.

Answer (score 6):

To add on to @wakachamo's answer, click the icon indicated by the red arrow to reveal the "two sections, 'PROJECT' and 'TARGETS'. Select the item under 'PROJECT', and then, select the 'General' tab. You should see it there."

[image: where the KEY button is]